# How to view Transactional Send Definitions in the Salesforce UI?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, transactional-messaging-api

So I created this transactional send definition  [with the api here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_transactional_messaging_email/createSendDefinition.html) and now I was wondering if there is a way to view it in the UI. I can't seem to find anything that indicates this is possible. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> options.createJourney  boolean     A value of true updates the send definition to make it available in Journey Builder as a Transactional Send Journey. After the definition is tied to a Transactional Send Journey, the definition remains part of Journey Builder. You can’t unlink a journey from a definition without recreating the transactional send definition.

Answer (score -1):

For a slightly different endpoint interaction/v1/eventDefinitions you could add below in the main JSON tree (request payload):

```
"isVisibleInPicker": true
```

You could add below attribute as well to control the visual representation of a definition:

```
"iconUrl": "/events/images/icon_journeyBuilder-event-api-blue.svg"
```

You would then have to create a journey and attach that defintion.

Adding an email activity of a transactional send type to the Journey payload would make you achieve your goal (triggering transactional emails via API and having send definition visible via UI): POST: /interaction/v1/interactions -> EMAILV2: configurationArguments.triggeredSend.sendClassificationId

It would be a different endpoint though so we're talking about a workaround of some sort.

Comment: Where in the salesforce UI would I see the send definition?

Comment: There's event definitions drop-down menu in Journey Builder App - you should see one there

Comment: Events -> entry sources

Comment: Tried to do it, but get this error: "Unrecognized field name isVisibleInPicker"

Comment: Ah right - I was using interaction/v1/eventDefinitions. I am using entry type of "Event" which is an API type. You could add an email activity then of a transactional type I presume when creating a journey using such event: POST: interaction/v1/interactions - triggeredSend.sendClassificationId would control the classification. It is not strictly transactional event send definition though